# Is is possible to get boids data to animation nodes signalling when they are 'attacking'?

Tags: animation, node-editor, particles, animation-nodes

I am creating a space dogfighting scene and I have been able to hook up the particle boids to animation node instances, including positions and even the rotations by normalizing the velocity and finding the difference between that and a base rotation.

I now wish to trigger animations based on either when the boid is in 'fight state' or perhaps if there could be a trigger based on a raycast or intersection with a parented invisible cone/pyramid and the enemy boid. I would then have my spacefighters animate and 'shoot'. (Ideally generating 'bullets' but that is another problem.)

I had a cursory glance at the boids code and am not sure if it is indeed possible, as the 'attack' seems to not be a 'state' but a simple operation where the 'target's 'health' is subtracted when in range.

*In Response to Omar:*
All the settings for who is an enemy and friend are in the particle settings when you change 'Physics' to 'Boids', then under 'Relations', I have referenced other objects also with 'boid' particle physics.
I cannot reveal any images as this project is under a NDA.
Thank you for your interest in helping me Omar.

Comment: Can you share what currently have? What is this "fight state"? How do you  define it? How do you define the enemy boid?

Comment: In light of the NDA, is think it would still be helpful to construct a minimal working example. (A blend with 2 planes and some particles *fighting* uploaded to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com.)